# How to use Apache Camel Master Component with Endpoint-DSL

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have the following code snippet that periodically starts a timer with a leader election mechanism.

```
@Produces
public LambdaRouteBuilder routes() {
    return rb -> rb.from("master:timer-ns:timer:foo")
            .to(log("com.example"));
}
```

I want to rewrite it with Endpoint-DSL syntax.

I found that master component available in Endpoint-DSL in `StaticEndpointBuilders`. But there is no method to set delegate endpoint to it.
For example:
`StaticEndpointBuilders.master("master-ns", StaticEndpointBuilders.timer("foo))`

Any help on that?